# Renaming/Prefixing classes for COM Interop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com, com-interop

Is there a way to prefix a c# class with its namespace when exposing it via COM Interop?

In Visual Studio if you allow the setting 'Make assembly COM-Visible' it will do this by default but I don't want to expose the whole library, I just want to be able to prefix a few visible classes with their namespace.

Does this have to be done manually by generating particular files or is there another way like adding an attribute to the class to achieve this?

Comment: Just don't use the checkbox.  Apply the [ComVisible(true)] attribute to the classes you want to be visible instead.

Comment: Hmm I edited my question because I think what I'm asking has come across wrong. Essentially I want to know how to prefix classes with the namespace like Visual Studio does.

Comment: This only ever happens by accident and cannot be controlled directly.  The type library exporter must do this when the prefix is necessary to avoid a duplicate definition.  No namespace support in COM so it is the only thing it can do to avoid the problem.  When you export everything then the odds for such an accident are much higher.  You can't rely on accidents.

Comment: So it only does it if it spots conflicts in the registry? I'm not relying on Visual Studio to do this. I'm trying to figure out a way to modify the generated tlb file so I can prefix namespaces on myself.

Comment: No, conflicts in the type library.  The same conflict you'd have if you removed all namespaces from your project.  It is a bit worse since in C# is okay to have, say, an enum member with the same name as a method and to have the same name for a method and a type.  Not okay in COM.

Comment: Thanks. Looking through some code it seems that these accidents started occurring due to refactored classes. On the plus side these accidents did give me the idea for prefixing namespaces onto classes!

Comment: Discovering that these were indeed accidents puts you on the right path.  Picking good names is very important, refactor some more.  You can get a preview of the type library with OleView.exe, File > View Typelib.

Comment: So basically you want to rename your classes to something else (Namespace+ClassName). Are there too many to not do it using the Refactor>Rename option in the right click popup menu?

Comment: I wanted to know if there were ways to (probably manually) generate the tlb file and concatenate the namespace to the front of the class. I don't want my classes in their libraries to be refactored to it. Visual Studio manages to do it but I am unable to find any sources online on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class's access modifier to internal, rather than public. This way only those that are public will be exposed.

Comment: This is an interesting approach but it would mess with Unit testing.

Comment: @C.Carter Would [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) work for your unit testing requirements?

Comment: Yes that works although the answer to the question was semi misinterpreted (I edited the question to try and be a bit more clear). I'm trying to prefix classes with their namespaces but can't find any information online to do that. The original question was interpreted as me trying to make specific classes visible

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the `ProgId` of the class when exposed by COM Interop?

If you add the `ComVisible` attribute to a class, it will have the namespace-qualified class name as its `ProgId` by default:

```
namespace MyCompany.MyNamespace
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class MyComVisibleClass
    {
        // ProgId will be MyCompany.MyNamespace.MyComVisibleClass

        ... Implementation

    }
}
```

But you can add a `ProgIdAttribute` to specify anything you like for the ProgId:

```
namespace MyCompany.MyNamespace
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ProgId("Anything.I.Like")]
    public class MyComVisibleClass
    {
        // ProgId will be Anything.I.Like

        ... Implementation

    }
}
```

Comment: No it's more that I have C# code that is being exposed to some VB6 code but I want the C# code to be easily distinguishable from the VB6 code.